# Deploying with capistrano fails - fatal: HTTP request failed. Requesting github, when set to bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, capistrano

So I've been deploying with Capistrano for quite some time now. Everything was good. Recently I ran into some issues.

The process was simple. I have a **bitbucket** account. I would push there and then cap would take the remote repo and then push it to the remote server. In doing so, upon using `cap deploy` I would be prompted twice for password; and actually, I don't even really know why it asked me for a password twice (**so perhaps this could have some light shed on it**). Nonetheless, it worked for a long time, then it randomly stopped working. Upon requesting a password the second time, it was now saying **`fatal: HTTP request failed`**.

To make matters even more confusing, I looked over the process and it's requesting a repo from a **github** after the second password prompt...and not **bitbucket**. There was a time when I used github, but that was in the past. So, I looked for a reference to the github repo in my Capfile and my deploy.rb, not finding any reference to it.

**Where is this and why is it requesting it?
How can I fix this?**

For reference, here is my deploy.rb (with sensitive info taken out of course):

```
set :application, "Application"
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/apps/app"
set :password, "webhostpassword"
set :user, "webhostuser"
set :domain, "webhostip"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false 
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "https://username@bitbucket.org/account/app.git"
set :scm_username, "repousername"
set :scm_passphrase, "repopassword"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

role :web, domain                           # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                           # This may be the same as your 'Web' server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true  

default_run_options[:pty] = true

namespace :deploy do
 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

and here the output where it is failing:

```
servers: ["webhostip"]
[webhostip] executing command
** [webhostip :: out] Password:
Password:
** [webhostip :: out]
** [webhostip :: out] error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
while accessing https://repo@github.com/repo/app.git/info/refs
**
** fatal: HTTP request failed
←[2;37mcommand finished in 18881ms←[0m
```

Notice line 6 and 7 where it is accessing github after it asks for the password (this is the second time a password prompt comes up upon using `cap deploy`

Answer (score 1):

In my guess, capistrano will do a `git pull origin <branch>` instead of `git clone <repo url>` if the repo already exists on the remote server. Hence, it is still trying to hit github url.

You can verify this by checking the `.git/config` file on your remote server. or by running `git remote -v` command. If `origin` is pointing to `github`, change that to `bitbucket`. Then manually run a `git pull origin master` command to ensure it is working

Comment: Did a `git remote -v`. it responded with this `$ git remote -v
origin  https://jshbrmn@bitbucket.org/2gen/ecosynthetix.git (fetch)
origin  https://jshbrmn@bitbucket.org/2gen/ecosynthetix.git (push)`

Comment: You may also want to check if you have github references in your local `.git/config`, since capistrano run local git commands (by a long shot a solution, but worth checking).

Comment: On both my remote (webhost) and local servers, the origins are the same (bitbucket).

Comment: can you manually run `cd /home/user/apps/app && git pull origin master` on your temote server?

Comment: returned this `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:...`